# load command prompt from ie9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cmd

How can i execute a command prompt command from ie9?

I know that this:

```
file:///c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

loads it up but how to add a command to that?

Comment: what are you try to do ? This commands can not call from programming but only from the user, and actually is call the windows sell to execute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IE is not actually execute the command, is just transfer it to the windows shell - meaning that Microsoft have merge IE with Windows Shell to make the user interface more friendly - so calling this from the url, you are not actually do something with the browser.

This commands may execute only interactivity on the browser url and can not be call them programmatically for obvious reasons... like that:

```
file:///c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe del c:\*.*
```

Comment: Yes I don't want Ie to run anything, simply to be able to make a link and click on it. I suppose the easiest way it to make a batch file and just run that.

Comment: @user1468537 where do you won this to run ? on client or on server ? As is the question is looks that you won to make it on client.

Comment: Yes the client, to use its own cmd but run a batch file from the server.

Comment: @user1468537 I think you are totally lost - If you won to run a set of commands on server there is a solution.